# xCache для PHP 5.3.18 на CentOS 5

Tags: centos

**Задача:** установить xCache на VPS под CentOS.

**Мои действия:**

```
wget http://xcache.lighttpd.net/pub/Releases/3.0.0/xcache-3.0.0.tar.gz
tar -xvf xcache-3.0.0.tar.gz
cd xcache-3.0.0/
phpize
./configure --enable-xcache
make
make install
```

В `php.ini` прописал расширение. Apache перезагрузил.

**Проблема:**

```
php -v-
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: XCache: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: XCache: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0    PHP 5.3.18 (cli) (built: Oct 22 2012 10:46:32)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

---

```
# phpize -v
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
```

---

```
# which phpize
/usr/bin/phpize
```

Comment: Module compiled with module API=20060613PHP    compiled with module API=20090626These options need to match - это надеюсь понятно?! Тока я так с ходу не скажу из-за чего оно так...

Comment: Не понятно.

Comment: Попробуйте phpize5

Comment: @mantigatos, что это?

Comment: Это команда для настройки окружения сборки. Вместо `phpize`

Comment: -bash: phpize5: command not found

Comment: У вас что-то не то с версиями php.Покажите вывод `phpize -v`   и  `which phpize`

Comment: UPD вопроса.